# How to install libraries?

Tags: installation, package-management, libraries

When I was installing the application (tracker-0.10.24) I've got this message:

```
Package requirements (glib-2.0     >= 2.26.0
                      gobject-2.0  >= 2.26.0
                      gio-unix-2.0 >= 2.26.0
                      dbus-1       >= 1.3.1
                      dbus-glib-1  >= 0.82) were not met:

No package 'dbus-1' found
No package 'dbus-glib-1' found
```

I can go to ubuntu packages and install them step by step, but I think here's should be more convenient way. How to install all these libraries?

Comment: Assuming you are using `apt`, try running `apt-get install -f <package-name>`.

Comment: For example what should I write for glib: 'apt-get install -f glib-2.26.0', is it right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Presumably this is an error from a `configure` script?

The error is referring to [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) package files.  These do not correspond one-to-one with Ubuntu/Debian package names (since they are not Debian or Ubuntu specific).

In this particular case, the `dbus-1.pc` file is found in the `libdbus-1-dev` Ubuntu package, and `dbus-glib-1.pc` is found in the `libdbus-glib-1-dev` Ubuntu package.  Installing those two should satisfy the dependencies of that `configure` script check.

Comment: 1.You're right 2. I've installed libdbus-1-dev and dbus-glib-1-dev and then I've got another errors 'No package 'sqlite3' found No package 'uuid' found'. I've tried to install them too: 'apt-get install sqlite3' and 'apt-get install uuid', it installed successfully but didn't help. How do you know which exactly package to install?

Comment: You can easily do package searches using `apt-cache search`.  Searching for `sqlite3` shows `libsqlite3-dev` as one of the answers, so that is probably what you want.  Similarly, you probably want `uuid-dev`.  Now given that tracker has already been packaged in Ubuntu, one option would be to install the build requirements for that package: that should easily be enough to let you build it from source.  You can do that using the command `apt-get build-dep tracker`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. First check your ubuntu version by running the command `lsb_release -a`.
Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/, search package name what do you want like your ubuntu version.

Example:

```sh
sudo apt-get install glib-2.0
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev
```

Note: install with version, not package name!

Comment: This answer is very much vague. Could you describe more?